# LOOP PROBLEMS in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop

I am creating a math tutorial app for kids in the primary level. And I am having a hard time in creating a loop that would generate 2 random numbers,then check if the answer is right/wrong for 5 times. also, the button would be disabled after clicking 5 times. The other things are clear to me except the idea of how to put it in a loop. can someone help me please? thanks! I tried using the FOR LOOP, but sadly, it would just loop 5 times but it would only check the answer 1 time.I need it to check 5 different answers.

```
  For ctr As Integer = 1 To 5
        Button3.Enabled = False
        initialize()
        If TextBox3.Text = sum Then
            MsgBox("correct")
            point = point + 1

            TextBox3.Focus()
        Else
            MsgBox("wrong")

            MsgBox(sum)
            TextBox3.Focus()

        End If
    Next
    MsgBox(point)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you are having trouble with. If your `For` loop executes 5 times and the code doing the checking is inside the loop, it should be executed 5 time as well. You do need to make sure that the code checks something different each time round the loop.

Comment: that's my idea sir , i need the loop to check 5 different answers . but the problem is my loop checks the same answer for 5 times :( can you help me ? please. thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code. I don't see how anyone can help you without seeing the code.

Comment: apologies, sir. first time to post here. I am so sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process five different TextBoxes in a loop, one way to do that is to create an array containing all the TextBoxes and loop through the array.

```
Dim boxes() As TextBox = {TextBox3, TextBoxX, TextBox22, TextBoxBB, TextBoxA}
For Each box As TextBox in boxes
    box.Focus()
    If box.Text = sum Then
        MsgBox.("correct")
        point += 1
    Else
        MsgBox("wrong")
    End If
Next
```

Alternatively, if you want the user to enter five answers one at a time in a single TextBox, you can have the user click a button each time an answer is entered. You should define the counter outside  the button's click handler.

```
Private ctr As Integer

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ctr += 1
    If ctr > 5 Then Button3.Enabled = False
    initialize()
    If TextBox3.Text = sum Then
        MsgBox("correct")
        point += 1
    Else
        MsgBox("wrong")
        MsgBox(sum)
    End If
    MsgBox(point)
End Sub
```

Comment: what if I have only one textbox, and then I want my loop to check 5 different answers that the user entered in that textbox ? is that possible sir? Because I have a function that would generate random number from 1 to 15 sir, it is the initialize() function. thanks tho for your  additional idea! :)

Comment: @rookProgrammer Do you mean the user enters 5 different answers in the TextBox at the same time (if so, how are the answers separated)? Or do you want the user to enter one answer and then after you check it, the user enters another, and so one for a total of five times?

Comment: the second one sir, that's exactly my idea.

Comment: @rookProgrammer I have added this second approach to my answer.

Comment: Okay, everything seems clear to me now, If there will be minor errors, then Im just gonna solve it by myself then. So I can test my logic. Thank you very much for your time sir ! Can I ask here everytime I cant solve my problem anymore?('cause I have limited knowledge yet, not like you guys who are already 'veterans' in programming :) ) or I am only allowed to ask one time? ('cause honestly I am really new to these kind of forum stuff. :D )

Comment: Also, it seems like an improvised LOOP ? Am I right sir? @Blackwood? :)

Comment: @rookProgrammer You could think of it that way. The idea is that after each answer you need to give the user the opportunity to type a new answer and then do something (click the button) to let your program know to check it.